# Splitting up large iOS View Controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a view table view controllers that contain a fairly large set of functionality and many lines of code - Is there an accepted way to split the single controller into multiple controllers or objects to help make it more readable and easier to navigate/maintain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are ways to make your code more modular. First off using a UITableView there is a Delegate and a DataSource. You can create separate NSObject classes for each of these.

The DataSource class would contain things like `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. With the full list here: [UITableViewDataSource](http://tableView%3anumberOfRowsInSection%3a).

The Delegate class would contain things like: `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. WIth the full list of here: [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)

It really matter on where most of your code is. If its all in creating a custom cell create a class for that and just send it the info it needs to build its self.

Comment: I had completely forgot about the difference between DataSource and Delegate - That will help break up the class enough. This is exactly what I needed - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use two subclasses of UIView (or tableView depending on what your are doing) to make the View code a bit more modular. Without more details on what you are attempting it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: frankly, i cannot see why this would be downvoted. It is a flawless answer. Im re-upvoting it.